# how to hide a div on focus-out of child elements of that div(in java script)

Tags: javascript

I want to hide a div on focusout of its child elements.say,

lets have username and password field in a div,it will be minimized initially, user will clicks opens the div then if user click anywhere outside the div should close the `mydiv`

```
<body>

<div id="mydiv" onblur="alert('hi');" tabindex="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">click off me to activate onblur
    <br/>
    username: <input type="text" name="username" onblur="alert('hi');" tabindex="1" />
    <br/>
   Password: <input type="text" name="password" />

    </div>
</body>
```

(see the JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vC7Rb/1/)

I tried putting onblur for both div as well as text field but that require common function call from which I need to check if any of the element is still have focus and then only hide the div.thats seems too much, so is there any simple way to do this.

I want implement this in pure javascript code and it should be compatible in all browser(IE,firefox,chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you are asking about how to detect a click outside an element. That question is asked and answered nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element). In addition, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Rvd4/) showing how to handle both the hiding and reshowing nicely with your use-case. The only thing I really added was showing that whatever button/methodology you use to reshow the username/password div will need to use the same sort of event.stopPropagation() to avoid re-hiding what you are trying to show.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('loginContainer').style.display='block';event.stopPropagation();">Show Login</button>
<div id="loginContainer" onclick="containerClicked(event)" style="border:1px solid black">
    <div><span>User Name:</span><input id="username" /></div>
    <div><span>Password:</span><input id="password" type="password"/></div>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red">Some other div on document</div>
```

JS:

```
document.onclick = function(){
    console.warn('doc clicked');
    document.getElementById('loginContainer').style.display = 'none';
}
function containerClicked(ev)
{
    console.warn('clicked');
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear,irrespective of whether user fills text field or not, if user clicks anywhere outside  the div, should close the div("mydiv").

Comment: Altered answer now that I understand the question.